# Buscador en capas C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**Cree este procedimeinto para un buscador en c#**

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[BuscarTareas]
@Condicion nvarchar(30)
as
select *from tbltareas where DocRefe like @Condicion+'%' or NomTarea like @Condicion+'%'
```

**De esta manera lo llame en la capadatos en visual studio C#**

```
 public void BuscarTareas(string Condicion)
        {
            Comando.Connection = conexion.AbrirConexion();
            Comando.CommandText = "BuscarTareas";
            Comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Condicion", Condicion);
            Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Comando.Parameters.Clear();
        }
```

**hasta acá todo bien, creo yo al ir a la capa presentación, tengo el siguiente código pero me sale esto, no se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'void' en 'object**

```
 private void BuscarTareas(string condicion)
    {
        Consultas objtarea = new Consultas();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = objtarea.BuscarTareas(condicion);  no se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'void' en 'object
    }
```

**Codigo del texbox para buscar**

```
private void txtBuscar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BuscarTareas(txtBuscar.Text);
    }
```

**me pueden ayudar con esto porfa**

Comment: creaste un trigger, no sera un stored procedure ?

Comment: Si perdón, ya lo corregí me ayudas ¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes que nada, ese es un stored procedure.

En cuanto al error en tiempo de compilación, es debido a que tu método BuscarTarea de la capa datos no evuelve nada (void) y en la capa presentación se lo estás asignando a un DataSource.

Tendrías que devolver un DataTable para asignarlo al DataSource:

```
public DataTable BuscarTareas(string Condicion)
{
    Comando.Connection = conexion.AbrirConexion();
    Comando.CommandText = "BuscarTareas";
    Comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Condicion", Condicion);

    // En esta parte, llenas el objeto dt con los datos de la consulta
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Comando))
    {
        adapter.Fill(dt);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Ahora, no se me hace tan familiar la forma en la que accedes a la base de datos. Te dejo un link para que puedas revisarla a profundidad: [Acceso a base de datos ADO.NET](https://elvex.ugr.es/decsai/csharp/databases/index.xml)

Comment: Hola, Amigo me funciono muchas gracias,  pero al copiar para buscar los datos y al mostrar es lentísimo a que se debe esto ¿?

Comment: Puede deberse a muchas cosas. Puede deberse al número de registros que haya en la base de datos, a si pintas el datagridview para visualización, o si la tabla a la que le aplicas el filtro tiene los índices adecuados. Revisa esos aspectos para poder mejorar el performance. Una opción sería cargar todos los datos a un datatable desde el incio y hacer el filtro con Linq sobre ese datatable para no estarse conectanda a la base de datos.

Comment: Solo tengo 3 registros y es lentísimo :(

Comment: Tienes algo de donde guiarme para que no se vea tan lento ¿?